# Group retrieved records from a RECURSIVE query, that have the same parents, grandparents

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I have a table with Item(s) than are in a ManyToMany Relationship with Category.

Item

```
id  |  name 
 1     name1
 2     name2
 3     name3
```

ItemCategory

```
id | category_id | item_id
  1     4            1
  2     5            1
  3     7            1
  4     8            1
```

Category (parent_id foreign key to itself)

```
  id | parent_id | name     
   1     Null       A1
   2      1         B1
   3      1         B2 
   4      2         C1
   5      3         C2
   6      1         D1
   7      6         DE
   8      1         DT
```

I'm trying to get the Item Categories, from child to parent, for an Item so I use:

```
 WITH RECURSIVE descendants(name, id, slug, parent_id, bread_order) AS (
 SELECT  name, id, slug, parent_id, 0
 FROM categories
 where id in (
 SELECT c.id FROM items AS p
 INNER JOIN items_categories AS pc ON p.id=pc.item_id 
 INNER JOIN categories AS c ON pc.category_id = c.id
     WHERE p.id = 10
 )   
 UNION ALL
 SELECT c2.name, c2.id, c2.slug, c2.parent_id, bread_order+1
 FROM categories AS c2
 INNER JOIN descendants AS d ON c2.id=d.parent_id
) SELECT id, name, parent_id, bread_order FROM descendants 
ORDER by bread_order DESC
```

The problem is that two child Categories can have the same parent, or a parent for one is grand parent for the other.

```
C1 -> B1 -> A1
C2 ->B1  -> A1
C3 ->B2  -> A1
DE -> D1 -> A1
DT  -> A1
```

I tried to group them but, because have the same parents, grand_parents is not what I need, I need when I retrieve the information from database to know how to make the path(See above).

Is there any way, like using CASE with the IDs that returns from the subquery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate the path during the query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE descendants(name, id, parent_id, bread_order, path) AS (
  SELECT  name, id, parent_id, 0, array[id] as path
  FROM categories
  where id in (SELECT c.id
               FROM items AS p
                 JOIN items_categories AS pc ON p.id=pc.item_id 
                 JOIN categories AS c ON pc.category_id = c.id
               WHERE p.id = 1)   
  UNION ALL

  SELECT c2.name, c2.id, c2.parent_id, bread_order+1, d.path||c2.id
  FROM categories AS c2
    JOIN descendants AS d ON c2.id=d.parent_id
) 
SELECT id, name, parent_id, path, bread_order
FROM descendants 
ORDER by path
```

Comment: it is ok, using path the only issue is that the correct path is on top parent not on start child